# Connecting to database in Node.js from routes

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, routes

I'm working on a express server and am having trouble accessing my database from a route file I have set up for users. When I attempt to make a get request I receive this as an error.

"code": "ER_NO_DB_ERROR",
  "errno": 1046,
  "sqlState": "3D000",
  "index": 0

I have been trying to look for a solution online but most of the answers suggest requiring db.js file everywhere which I already do. I have a feeling I need to pass the connection I made in app.js around but I am not sure how to do this. The relevant parts of my files are below. Database login info has been redacted, I do get a successful connection in app.js. I'm fairly new to this so any help would be appreciated, specifically if there is a better way to use the pool implemented in db.js.

app.js

```
      var express = require('express');
      var path = require('path');
      var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
      var logger = require('morgan');
      var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
      var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

      var index = require('./routes/index');
      var users = require('./routes/users');
      var mysql = require('mysql')
      var app = express();
      var users = require('./routes/users');
      var media = require('./routes/media');
      var tv = require('./routes/tv');
      var movies = require('./routes/movies');
      var db = require('./db.js')

      var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        port: '3306',
        host: '*********************',
        user: '********',
        password: '******'
       })

      db.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Unable to connect to MySQL.')
          process.exit(1)
        } else {
            console.log('Successfully connected')
          }
        })

      app.use('/api', users);
```

models/user.js

```
    var db = require('../db.js');
    var passwordHash = require('password-hash');


    exports.getAll = function(done) {
      db.get().query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, rows) {
        if (err) return done(err)
        done(null, rows)
      })
    }
```

routes/users.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router()
    var user = require('../models/user');
    var db = require('../db.js');

    //this doesn't prInt anything currently. This is prompting me to believe I         somehow         
    //need to pass a connection object or am using the pool properly.
    console.log(db.get());

    router.route('/users').get(function(req, res) {
      user.getAll(function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
           return res.send(err);
         }
         res.json(users);
       });
    });
```

db.js

//this is taken mostly from a tutorial I found online

```
    var mysql = require('mysql')
      , async = require('async')

    var PRODUCTION_DB = 'app_prod_database'
      , TEST_DB = 'app_test_database'

    exports.MODE_TEST = 'mode_test'
    exports.MODE_PRODUCTION = 'mode_production'

    var state = {
      pool: null,
      //mode: null,
    }

    exports.connect = function(done) {
      state.pool = mysql.createPool({
        port: '3306',
        host: '***************',
        user: '*********',
        password: '*******'
        //database: mode === exports.MODE_PRODUCTION ? PRODUCTION_DB : TEST_DB
      })

      //state.mode = mode
      done()
    }

    exports.get = function() {
      return state.pool
    }

    exports.fixtures = function(data) {
      var pool = state.pool
      if (!pool) return done(new Error('Missing database connection.'))

      var names = Object.keys(data.tables)
      async.each(names, function(name, cb) {
        async.each(data.tables[name], function(row, cb) {
          var keys = Object.keys(row)
            , values = keys.map(function(key) { return "'" + row[key] + "'" })

          pool.query('INSERT INTO ' + name + ' (' + keys.join(',') + ') VALUES         (' + values.join(',') + ')', cb)
        }, cb)
      }, done)
    }

    exports.drop = function(tables, done) {
      var pool = state.pool
      if (!pool) return done(new Error('Missing database connection.'))

      async.each(tables, function(name, cb) {
        pool.query('DELETE * FROM ' + name, cb)
      }, done)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either supply a valid database in the createConnection...

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    port: '3306',
    host: '*********************',
    user: '********',
    password: '******',
    database: 'mydatabase'
```

And/or, qualify the table name with the name of the database in the query:

```
   db.get().query('SELECT * FROM mydatabase.users',
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

What it looks like is happening in the current code, a connection is established to the MySQL Server. But no `USE mydatabase` statement has been executed.  When the SQL statement `SELECT ... FROM users` is executed, MySQL doesn't know which database the `users` is supposed to reference. (That table could exist in multiple databases containing a table or view named `users`.)

That's what's causing the 1046 No database selected error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i added this and am now getting a   "code": "ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR",
  "errno": 1044, Which is progress. I will look more into why I am not able to properly access my tables from here